# Combine rows of pandas dataframe if values from multiple columns are the same and combine strings from one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this pandas dataframe coded in a python jupyter notebook as an example:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
-------------------
"a" |"b" |0   |"d"
"a" |"b" |1   |"e"
```

I am trying to combine rows into one that has the exact same values in col1 and col2, and concatenate col4 values. This would be the intended result:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
-------------------
"a" |"b" |0   |"de"
```

I have tried using the pandas aggregate function but I am still not getting what I want by concatenating string from col4.

Thank you so much guys for your help!

Comment: `df.groupby(['col1','col2'], as_index=False).agg({'col3':'first', 'col4':''.join})`

Comment: Hold on I will try it thank you I will update you asap